# Pointers swap values in void function, but won't return swapped values

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to swap two strings passed in as `char` pointers.

In debugging, I get the right answers at the end of the called function, but returning the values after the function ends returns the same values as passed in.  Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char *s1, *s2;
  s1 = "12345678";
  s2 = "87654321";

  printf("s1 is %s\n", s1);
  printf("s2 is %s\n", s2);
  strswap(s1, s2);
  printf("s1 is now %s\n", s1);
  printf("s2 is now %s\n", s2);
}
```

and the code for the function itself

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strswap(char *s1, char *s2){
    char *temp;

    temp = s1;
    printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
    s1 = s2;
    printf("s1: %s\n", s1);
    s2 = temp;
    printf("s1: %s\n", s1);
    printf("s2: %s\n", s2);
    printf("temp: %s\n", temp);
}
```

Comment: I can change the name of the function, just not the params.

Comment: Also, we are unable to use any standard library functions other than printf.

Comment: What is the *exact* statement of the problem you're trying to solve?  What you've posted doesn't seem quite complete.  Because given the function prototype you seem constrained by, it's **impossible** to safely swap the strings.  The only way to do it given C is pass-by-value is to swap the string contents.  But the memory that holds either string may not be writable, and the strings might be of different length.

Comment: Write a function that swaps two character strings AT s1 and s2. assume both to be the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I order to swap strings, first of all you can't just use constant string literals since they are immutable. Assigning string literal to `char *` is considered bad practice unless you properly know what you're trying to achieve. Read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547979/c-string-immutable) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/183842/is-initializing-a-char-with-a-string-literal-bad-practice) also. You should use statically/dynamically allocated strings.

As other people said, you're passing the character pointers by value, so any changes you make in `strswap()` would not be reflected in main function. Since some local variables are modified and they get destroyed when control goes out of those functions. You should either pass `char **` like in one of the mentioned answers. I would recommend to use statically allocated strings and use `strcpy` for string copy operations like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 1000

void strswap(char *s1, char *s2){
    char tempStr[MAX_SIZE];
    strcpy(tempStr, s1);
    strcpy(s1, s2);
    strcpy(s2, tempStr);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char aString1[MAX_SIZE] = "Rohan", aString2[MAX_SIZE] = "Rohit";

    printf("s1 is %s\n", aString1);
    printf("s2 is %s\n", aString2);
    strswap(aString1, aString2);
    printf("s1 is now %s\n", aString1);
    printf("s2 is now %s\n", aString2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your links solved my issue.  Thanks, I wasn't aware c-strings could be passed in as pointers.

Answer (score -1):

C uses pass-by-value for function argument passing.

Here, the pointers themselves are passed by value, so any changes made to the pointers (for example, assigning values to them), will not be reflected to the actual arguments in the caller. However, if any change is made to the value stored at the memory location pointed to by the pointers, that would be *reflected* to the actual arguments used to call the function from the caller.

So, to change a pointer value itself, you need to pass a pointer to the pointer.

Comment: So how can I change the values passed in as if they are by reference in a void function?  The prototype is how the function is meant to be written.

Comment: @Avallauch in that case, you need to copy the contents, not assign the starting pointer. Be aware, to copy the contents, the memory location must be writable!!

Comment: @SouravGhosh The pointers aren't `const`, so they are assumed to be writable by the function.

Comment: I'd appreciate a note with a DV.

Comment: Not my downvote, but the arguments are not the caller.

Comment: @SouravGhosh well, the caller is who made the call to the function, but the arguments are just arguments passed to the called function.

Comment: @machine_1 ahh...English. Any better?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I think you should also change the statement: `reflected to the caller` to `reflected to the original variables`.

Answer (score -2):

You're using string literals to initialize the pointers, you can't swap those strings with the function prototype you showed.

Assuming the string initialization is a mistake, we can do the swap without changing the function's prototype, by copying the actual characters around. This requires that the strings have equal length, otherwise the longer one can't be copied to the space used by the shorter one.

Here's an attempt:

```
void swap_strings(char *a, char *b)
{
  const size_t al = strlen(a);
  const size_t bl = strlen(b);
  if(al != bl)
    return;
  for(size_t i = 0; i < al; ++i)
  {
    const char t = a[i];
    a[i] = b[i];
    b[i] = t;
  }
}
```

I changed the function's name, I have a vague recollection that you're not supposed to add functions with names beginning with `str`, that's reserved.

Note: this requires that the strings be writable, so you can't use it on string literals. You have to have proper buffers (or arrays) like this:

```
char a[] = "foo";
char b[] = "bar";

swap_strings(a, b);
printf("'%s' and '%s'\n", a, b);
```

This will print `'bar' and 'foo'`.

Comment: This doesnt work for me - trying to set a[i] = b[i] just makes my program break and windows complains.

Comment: @Avallauch Okay, did you change the declarations of your strings like I did, to get modifiable arrays? That's very important, as numerous people have pointed out.

Comment: Yea I looked at it a bit more and finally got it.  Thanks for the help!